# render collection in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am tryin to pass a collection in ajax by js but dont work, dont render the collection,this is from one scaffold to another, I am trying this way:

```
$("#cobran_<%= @detalleco.IdCobranza %>").fadeOut(500, function(){
  $(this).remove();
  $(".child").remove();
  $("#container_cobranza").prepend('<%= j render :partial => "/cobranza/cobran", :collection => @detalleco.cobran, :as => :cobran  %>');

});
```

only remove the ids but dont render. It should render in this view:

```
<!--<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>-->
<style>
.container {
}

</style>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Cuentas por cobrar</h1>

  <br>
  <br>

  <div class="well center-block">
    <h2>Por favor selecciona la ruta </h2>


  </div>



  <table id="superior" class="display"><!--el id empresas es de datatables referenciado en empresas.coffe y display class es una clase de datatables-->
  <thead>

    <tr><!--active es para sombrear la fila-->
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Ruta</th>
      <th>Vendedor</th>
      <th>Cliente</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Razón Social</th>
      <th>Documento</th>
      <th>Saldo Inicial</th>
      <th>Abono</th>
      <th>Saldo Actual</th>
      <th>Fecha Reg</th>
      <th>Fecha Vence</th>
      <th>TipoDoc</th>
      <th>Acción</th>
      <th></th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody id="container_cobranza">
      <%= render @cobranza %><!--carga todos los empresas-->
</tbody>


</table>
</div >
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#container_cobranza").html("<%=escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'cobranza/cobran', cobran: @detalleco.cobran))%>");
```

instead of

```
$("#container_cobranza").prepend('<%= j render :partial => "/cobranza/cobran", :collection => @detalleco.cobran, :as => :cobran  %>');
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: this throw me this error: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `cobran' for #<#<Class:0x8361a020>:0x83f47530>
Did you mean?  cobran_url):
    1: <tr id="cobran_<%= cobran.id %>">
    2:   <td><%=cobran.id%>
    3: 
    4: 
  app/views/cobranza/_cobran.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_cobranza__cobran_html_erb___934401116__635218208'
  app/views/detallecob/create.js.erb:9:in `_app_views_detallecob_create_js_erb___78557686__1040567018'

Comment: you faced that error due to "@detalleco.cobran". I don't know how 'detalleco' related to 'cobran'

Comment: It supposed to that detalleco.cobran throws me all the data of the table cobran. this two tables are related, in the rails terminal I put Detalleco.last.cobran and throw me all the data from cobran.

Comment: I find the issue, I tryed this way:   <% @cobran=@detalleco.cobran %>

  $("#container_cobranza").html("<%=escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'cobranza/cobran', cobran: @cobran))%>");
 And Its works, but I'd have to change all the variables in the partial cobran.id to @cobran.id. also I have been tryed without the @ but i get the error :Error (undefined local variable or method cobran' for #<#<Class:0x8361a020>:0x83f47530>

Comment: So, what is the issue with '@' instance variable?

Comment: please check this post, I published it in detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40750318/fix-the-render-with-ajax-in-partial/40751013#40751013

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried:

```
$("#container_cobranza").prepend('<%= j(render(:partial => "/cobranza/cobran", :collection => @detalleco.cobran, :as => :cobran))  %>');
$("#cobran_<%= @detalleco.IdCobranza %>").fadeOut(500, function(){
  $(this).remove();
  $(".child").remove();
});
```

(I prefere to add the brackets to avoid any mistakes)